# Добавление посещения учеников в одном запросе

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Задача:** Одним нажатием занести в БД посещения учеников за текущий день.
Вывожу всех учеников, которые должны прийти сегодня. Создаю **checkbox** со значением "1" при посещении и "0" при пропуске урока.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "**добавить**", все эти значения добавились в отдельные поля в БД, одним запросом. 
**Вот так:** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, модно попробовать запустить цикл, по количеству этих значений, и в цикле добавлять запросы, или запустит цикл на созданиях мульти запроса, а в конце исполнить его.

Comment: Таблица по отношению к дате пишется последовательно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам запрос может выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE
SET visited = 1
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...);
```

Если использовать PDO можно сделать так.

Допустим у Вас есть массив айдишников;

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

создаём сроку из количества вопросов (?)

```
$place_holders = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
```

Создаём стороку запроса

```
$sql = "UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET visited = 1 WHERE id IN ($place_holders)";
```

Выполняем запрос

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql)->execute($ids);
```